# Grab info from excel file and send alert to the contact for each row. Need info to be consolidated into one email

Tags: excel, powershell

Currently there's an excel file with an "info" column and a "contact" column. I need to send the info to the contact. However, if I just iterate through the rows and send an email for each one, a contact will get hundreds of emails. How can I grab the info from each column and send it to the correct contact in a single email?

```
   (sendEmail function is up here) 
    Do
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i -le $rowMax - 1; $i++)
        {

            $words =  @"
            Hello $contactname, blablabla

    "@

               $toAddress = $contactemail
               $subject = "$warning" 
               $body = ($words)
               Write-Host ("sending email to " + $toAddress)
               sendEmail

        }
        #close excel file
        $objExcel.Quit()
    } #end of do
    While ($node.Length -ne 0)
```

Comment: With a loop and build a string? There are likely many ways to do this, what have you tried so far? Please show your relevant code in an [mcve].

Comment: Added some stripped down code for you! It's just a for loop that goes through, grabs the info in each column, and shoots out an email. I don't know a way to tell powershell to "save" the info for each unique contact into a variable to use later.

Comment: I don't see the code grabbing any of the info.. It just seems to iterate over a series of rows. Please also provide an exerpt of the actual data in the Excel file so we have beter understanding of what we are dealing with here.